# Setting maxpoolsize in springboot async will make my UI available only to 5 users?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

```
executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
```

I have a UI app and backend in Spring. One method takes 15 sec to execute. I am trying to handle it via spring-boot asyn..but setting this as 5 restrict UI users for that functionality to 5?

when we set it..is it for one instance? or for all the instance...say for example this code runs then only 5 threads will be there...say 10 users login to that app..threads are 5..do it means for next 5 users UI will not be accessible..

Answer (score 2):

**core pool size** - sets how many threads can run parallelly which means 5 users can access simultaneously. If more hits occur then it is stored in queue which is configured by setting **max pool size**

So, according to your configuration after 5 users the next five user requests will be in queue. After the queue is full all requests will be rejected.

Say if one request completes from the first five then one request out of the five in queue will start and so on.

Refer this for Threadpool reading in respect to spring-boot https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

Comment: Your welcome. If you are satisfied from the answer then please accept it as the answer to your question.